# Error 1 Character constant must contain exactly one character

Tags: vb.net

i wanted to open a myconnection but there is an error in my connection string. I need help in changing character or how to solve that error in my connection string?. pls help.

following is the code i am using

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="c:\users\samsung\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication2\WindowsApplication2\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
```

ur help is greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: can you post some snippet?

Comment: sorry im just new in this stock exchange

Comment: try the answer which i had posted below.

Answer (score 1):

change your connection string as follows:

```
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" & _
                                "c:\users\samsung\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication2\WindowsApplication2\Database1.mdf;" & _
                                "Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
```

or you can do like this also

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\samsung\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication2\WindowsApplication2\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
```

Comment: @AshleySmith which expression worked out for you? The first or the second one? By the way, you can accept the answer by clicking the check at the left side.